# How to solve dimensionality and sequentiality problems with LSTM input?

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I have two problem related to the input requirements for the LSTM model. My LSTM requires 3D input  as a tensor that is provided by a replay buffer (replay buffer itself is a deque) as a tuple of some components. LSTM requires each component to be a single value instead of a sequence.

**state_dim = 21;
batch_size = 32**

Problems:

1. NumPy array returned by batch sampling is one dimensional (1D), while required is 3D. Using np.reshape nor np.expand nor np.asarray does not work as it returns errors such as *ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 32 into shape (32,1,21)*
2. When using array broadcasting as a workaround (that was just testing, don't want to use broadcasting at all in my code) another error emerges when converting array into a tensor: *ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.*

structure of the code:

There is a function that returns state as a list of 21 features, let's call it **def get_state():**

then it gets used by this part of code:

```
def sample_batch():
    global batch_size
    batch_indices = np.random.randint(len(replay_buffer), size=batch_size)
    batch = [replay_buffer[index] for index in batch_indices]

    states = np.array([np.array(item[0], dtype=np.float32) for item in batch])
    actions = np.array([item[1] for item in batch])
    rewards = np.array([item[2] for item in batch])
    next_states = np.array([np.array(item[3], dtype=np.float32) for item in batch])
    done_flags = np.array([item[4] for item in batch])

    # Ensure states and next_states are 2-dimensional arrays - this is the workaround that was mentioned but it should not be in the final code
    if states.ndim == 1:
        states = states[:, np.newaxis]
    if next_states.ndim == 1:
        next_states = next_states[:, np.newaxis]

    n_timesteps = 1  # Specify the number of timesteps

    # Add a time_steps dimension to states and next_states using broadcasting - this is the workaround that was mentioned but it should not be in the final code
    states = states[:, np.newaxis, :] * np.ones((1, n_timesteps, 1), dtype=np.float32)
    next_states = next_states[:, np.newaxis, :] * np.ones((1, n_timesteps, 1), dtype=np.float32)

    # Convert to tensor
    states = tf.convert_to_tensor(states, dtype=tf.float32)
    next_states = tf.convert_to_tensor(next_states, dtype=tf.float32)

    return states, actions, rewards, next_states, done_flags

# Update the network based on target model Q-values
def update_network():
    global batch_size
    states, actions, rewards, next_states, done_flags = sample_batch()

    Q_values = model.predict(states)
    Q_values_next = target_model.predict(next_states)

    for i in range(batch_size):
        if done_flags[i]:
            Q_values[i][actions[i]] = rewards[i]
        else:
            Q_values[i][actions[i]] = rewards[i] + gamma * np.max(Q_values_next[i])

    model.train_on_batch(states, Q_values)


# Define max steps per episode
max_steps_per_episode = 1000

# Set the number of episodes over which to calculate the average reward
average_over_episodes = 5

# Initialize a list to store the rewards for each episode
episode_rewards = []

# Keep track of the best average reward
best_avg_reward = float('-inf')

# Definition of Q-learning + definition of state as state = get_state()
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    state = get_state()
    episode_reward = 0
    # Decay epsilon (episode - 1 is to start from initial value and then decay in the next episode)
    epsilon = initial_epsilon * (decay_rate ** (episode - 1))
    step = 0
    done = False

    while not done:
        # Choose action using epsilon-greedy policy
        if np.random.rand() < epsilon:
            action = np.random.randint(num_actions)
        else:
            Q_values_single = model.predict(np.array([state]))
            action = np.argmax(Q_values_single)

        # Take action and get reward
        take_action(action)
        reward = get_reward()
        next_state = get_state()

        # Add experience to replay buffer
        replay_buffer.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
```

BTW there are two models there: online model and target model:

```
# Choose optimizer:
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=alpha)

# Set up target model -- influenced by Deep Q-learning paper by Minh et al. (2015)
target_model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(None, state_dim)),
        layers.Dense(num_actions),
    ]
)
target_model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)


# Define a function to update the target network's weights
def update_target_network():
    target_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())


# Set up online model and load weights
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(None, state_dim)),
        layers.Dense(num_actions),
    ]
)

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
```

I did try various ways to solve those erros, as mentioned above, np.reshape, np.expand, np.asarray or using array broadcasting (that actually worked but revealed another problem with replay buffer component sequentiality) or dtype=np.float32.

If anyone has some ideas how to prepare LSTM input so that state feature data are both 3D array and each state array element is of single value (even though consisting of a sequence of 21 features) I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: What's the dtype of the array(s) in question?

Comment: @hpaulj dtype=np.float32

Comment: @hpaulj After spending some time with this I do believe the issue is with how the state data generated from get_state() function is: a) used as a sequence in replay buffer state component (here's the problem how to convert multiple feature state into a single value) and b) def sample_batch creates a 1D NumPy array that can't be converted into a 3D array required by LSTM

Comment: The reason I asked about dtype is that often people often ask about 1d object dtype arrays - the result of mixed sample sizes.

Comment: @hpaulj my size sample is a list of 21 floats so the 1d array is (21,) but I need it to be merged with batch_size 32 and another dimension to create 3D array